# Questions regarding the pair of Josephson equations

Tags: superconductivity, josephson-junction

The Josephson effect was somehow surprising because a current can flow without applying an external voltage. The pair of seminal equations are (I refrain of repeating what symbol is what)

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
I &= I_c\sin\varphi,\\
\frac{d\varphi}{dt} &=\frac{2\pi}{\Phi_0}V(t).
\end{split}
\end{equation}

I have a couple of doubts regarding these equations:

1. It may appear obvious but, the voltage $V(t)$ is it really the voltage contained in the device or an "external voltage" (like a battery)? By the device I mean the left/right superconductors are joined by the typical middle insulator.
2. If $V(t)$ is a self-voltage, couldn't happen that after some time $t$, just by the principle of least energy, both superconductors must achieve the same equilibrium state? Or is it more that the current oscillates according to the potential energy $\approx \cos\varphi$?

Answer (score 1):

The quantity $V$ is the potential difference across the junction. It does not matter where it comes from.  The quantity $\varphi$ is the difference in phase of the order parameter $\langle\psi\psi \rangle\propto e^{i\varphi}$.  The current depends only on this phase difference. This is Brian Josephson's great insight: a supercurrent current can flow through a barrier without a potential difference, but if a potential difference is present then  $\varphi$ will change with time and the current will oscillate.  This   AC Josephson effect  allows us to relate a frequency (easy to measure with great precision) to a voltage (not so easy to measure with precsision) via Planck's constant $\hbar$ which is hidden in $\Phi_0$.

Comment: Well, I'm actually curious whether voltage is applied or not externally, but your answer seems to imply that one can add it latter and have the phase difference change in time afterwards. I hope not having misunderstood it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a voltage "contained" by a device. Voltage is a quantity defined along a path joining two points in space (terminals in a circuit).

The constitutive equations for a device, like the Josephson equations, always describe *constraints* between quantities. That is, they define what are the pairs of quantity functions $(v(t),i(t))$ admissible at the device's terminals.

So the two equations that you have written relate the voltage *across* the two terminals of a *lumped* (that is, with negligible spatial extension) Josephson junction with the supercurrent crossing the junction.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers say: there is no difference between "voltage contained in the device or an "external voltage"": voltage is what you measure when you connect a voltmeter to two terminals, it does not matter how that voltage is 'created'.

For your second question, the following may help you understand.
If you have two independent superconductors with phases $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$, then the system of the two superconductors have a potential energy that is proportional to $\cos(\phi_1 - \phi_2)$. This is called the [Josephson energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephson_effect#Josephson_energy), and it is easily calculated as the time integral over the power $I \times V$, where $I$ and $V$ are the two expressions that you wrote down.

As such, a system of two superconductors that have a relative phase difference is not in equilibrium, but is in an excited state. Once you couple the superconductors via a Josephson junction, current can flow from one superconductor to the other, but if this combined system is completely isolated, it can of course not lose this energy. This is a general principle in physics. So indeed, if this system is completely isolated, the current will oscillate. This essentially a macroscopic version of [oscillations in two-level quantum systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-state_quantum_system).

This is however some idealized system that never occurs in the real world. To my knowledge, nobody has ever even tried to take two isolated superconductors and try to see whether a current flows when brought close together (such experiments have been carried out in atomic superfluid condensates though). The Josephson effect is always measured either in a circuit with applied current, or in a superconducting loop where supercurrent is induced via a magnetic field.